# WhatsApp can't use Google account for backup

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-account

My old phone just died on me yesterday. It used to back up the WhatsApp chat history to my main Google account, which I also used to register the device.

Now I have a new phone, and I registered it to the same Google account. After installing WhatsApp, I tried to restore the Google Drive backup to the new installation. However, when I try to enter my Google account, it tells me "This account already exists on your device"

Somehow after switching apps, WhatsApp assumed I don't want to restore a backup, and now I'm stuck with no history.

Also, when I try to set up the Google Drive backup on my new device, it gives me the same error when I try to enter my Google account; "This account already exists on your device". I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Is it just impossible to backup WhatsApp to an account already registered to the same device?

Comment: Nowadays, one can transfer the chat history without google backup, just by direct wifi/bluetooth connection and scanning a QR code on the new phone. The option for that is also available in the settings. See for example: https://faq.whatsapp.com/209942271778103/?cms_platform=android

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem on Android 13.
I fixed the problem by deleting the Google account and then in the application settings Google Play Service > Permissions.
Make sure there are no more denied permissions.
I deleted all WhatsApp data and then made sure there were no more denied permissions.
Then restarted the application.

I was able to add a Google account and find my backup !

Answer (score 1):

Did you already add that Google account while setting up the phone? Please check Settings > Users & accounts if that account is already added.
If it is, then try removing it and adding it again.

**P.S:** It may be called *Accounts* in older Android versions.

Comment: I had exactly the same *"This account already exists on your device"* notification without being able to actually select it. Removing the google account (with a reboot just in case), and re-adding, allowed WhatsApp to do backups to google drive again.

Comment: Just to be clear the tl;dr: this solution still works in 2022 (and has no data loss penalties, WhatsApp isn't affected and anything google resyncs immediately after re-adding) :)

Answer (score 1):

After several unsuccessful attempts to get Whatsapp to use my main google account, I just left it as it was. After a few weeks, Whatsapp notified me by itself that I should set up a backup plan. At that time, it *did* allow me to select the account I wanted to use, without a hassle.

Looks like the problem fixed itself over time.

Answer (score 0):

Not deliberately wanting to comment on a necro'd thread, BUT ... I literally just had exactly this issue, following a message from WhatsApp itself. However, the solution was quite simple:-

I forced a complete restart of the app by using the Android STOP option on the WhatsApp application; and Restarting it using the icon on the main screen.

Once that was done, it allowed me to setup the backup frequency on my existing Google account.